# How to send GCM Topic Message from Java Appengine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-messaging

To send a normal GCM, I can do

```
Sender sender = new Sender(apiKey);
Message message = new Message.Builder()
    .addData("message", "this is the message")
    .addData("other-parameter", "some value")
    .build();
Result result = sender.send(message, registrationId, numOfRetries);
```

Will someone please show how I might send a topic message from Appengine (Java)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this version of the [Java GCM library](https://github.com/google/gcm/pull/116). It will soon be merged into the master branch. It supports topic messaging. To send a topic message simply set the topic as the "to" field. Eg: /topics/mytopic

```
Sender sender = new Sender(apiKey);
sender.send(message, topic);
```

Comment: Do you mind providing a little bit more, like a code snippet as the OP provided? Also is there a gradle way to grab this library? Sorry if this is something obvious that I should know how to do.

Comment: Added snippet to answer. Making this available through gradle is currently being worked on.

Comment: When I change the method from:
sender.send(message, registrationId, numOfRetries);
to
sender.send(message, "/topics/global", numOfRetries);
I got invalidRegistration error on the app engine side. Looking at the code change at the library that you pointed it should have worked. Am I missing something? Please explain correct way to send message to topic from Endpoint code